# How can I apply a logical OR to a BINARY column so the result is all the correct values?

Tags: sql-server, binary, logical-operators, logical-or

I have a set of results that are stored in a binary(12) column. I'm looking for all the flags that have been set at various times for a particular condition.  It goes something like

| Status | Flags |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 0x000000000000000000002000 |
| 5678 | 0x000000000000000000000000 |
| 1234 | 0x000000000000000000000040 |

What I would like to do is write a query such as

```
SELECT Status, OR(Flags)
FROM StatusTable
GROUP BY Status
```

giving the result

| Status | OR(Flags) |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 0x000000000000000000002040 |
| 5678 | 0x000000000000000000000000 |

I can find examples that let me manually OR two values but nothing that applies an OR to a result column.  I've greatly simplified the example but we're talking thousands of values with thousands of statuses (mostly 0x000000000000000000000000) making it impractical to manually OR them. I suppose a function could be used and a cursor to loop each one but surely there's an out of the box solution to this?

Comment: T-SQL bitwise operators are limited to `int` types so you will need to substring the binary value into 4-byte segments. The function code will be rather ugly. Note that storing a bitmask in a relational database should generally be avoided as it violates the principle of atomic data.

Comment: I've inherited this so these are the cards I've been dealt.

Comment: *"I've inherited this so these are the cards I've been dealt."* Seems like a project to fix then, if you're in charge now. :)

Comment: Hahahaha I wish. It's quite central now so that would be a big change.  I was hoping for a quick win but it doesn't look likely now :(

Comment: Unfortunately there are often no "quick fixes" if the underlying design is flawed or not up to scratch. The quicker fix can often be the rebuild (even if that isn't quick), as it doesn't end up with constant work arounds and undesired (but expected) behaviour.

Comment: Do you want to group an arbitrary number of rows by `Status`, or will it always be two rows per `Status`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing this in TSQL would be hard, if you can not fix the underlaying design, you can write a .Net CLR User-Defined Aggregate.

In C# you have binary OR operator: [Bitwise and shift operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#logical-or-operator-).
You can follow this guide to write a CLR function:[CLR User-Defined Aggregates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-functions/clr-user-defined-aggregates-requirements?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: I'm not in a position to do this but I agree that it would resolve my issue. If I don't get a more suitable answer within a couple of days, I'll mark this as the answer despite it not being the ideal one for me.

Answer (score 0):

**T-SQL is pretty bad at bit-twiddling. But it does have `&` and `|`.** You need to break out each flag, aggregate it over the table then pack it back in

This query is not made any easier by the lack of binary `STRING_AGG`.

```sql
SELECT
    [Status],
    CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN byte = 1 THEN val END) AS binary(4)) +
    CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN byte = 5 THEN val END) AS binary(4)) +
    CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN byte = 9 THEN val END) AS binary(4)) AS OrFlags
FROM (
    SELECT [Status], v1.bytePos,
        MAX(CASE WHEN CAST(SUBSTRING(Flags, v1.bytePos, 4) AS int) & v2.bitt <> 0 THEN v2.bitt ELSE 0 END) AS val
    FROM @StatusTable
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(1),(5),(9)) v1(bytePos)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES
        (1),(2),(4),(8),(16),(32),(64),(128),(256),(512),(1024),(2048),(4096),(8192),(16384),(32768),(65536),(131072),(262144),(524288),(1048576),(2097152),(4194304),(8388608),(16777216),(33554432),(67108864),(134217728),(268435456),(536870912),(1073741824),(-2147483648)
    ) v2(bitt)
    GROUP BY [Status], v1.bytePos, v2.bitt
) t
GROUP BY Status
```

Steps are as follows:

- Take the base table, cross join `1,5,9` starting byte numbers for each 32-bit Integer.
- Cross-join again all bit-flags
- Group up by `Status` and position/flag
- Select out the `Status`, Integer position, and whether any value has this flag set
- Finally conditionally sum up the flags and convert results back into binary

---

**If you want to effect an `AND` aggregation change `MAX` to `MIN`.**

Comment: One of the solutions I came up with had a slight problem with using SUM because if, say bit 62, was repeated, it added up and created a bit 63.  I'll have a try of this tomorrow and see how it goes.

Comment: If you look carefully, I do a `MAX` for each bit, then sum up the bits. You could equally pivot them and add them with `+` for the same effect